# Como minimizar un PrimaryStage (Toda mi aplicación) desde una ventana secundaria

Tags: java

Tengo mi **primaryStage** compuesto de `BorderPane` y `MenuBar`, el cual lo tengo programado del siguiente modo.

```
public class Newtech extends Application 
{
   private static BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

   public static BorderPane getRoot() 
   {
      return root;
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
   {     
      URL menuBarUrl = getClass().getResource("FXMLMenu.fxml"); // 
      MenuBar bar = FXMLLoader.load(menuBarUrl);
      URL SceneCertificadoUrl = getClass().getResource("/certificado[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]/Certif.fxml");
      AnchorPane paneOne = FXMLLoader.load(SceneCertificadoUrl);

      root.setTop(bar);
      root.setCenter(paneOne);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setTitle("Newtech111");
      primaryStage.setResizable(false);
      primaryStage.show();        
   }
}
```

y que contienen los siguientes Item[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este punto programo un botón para que tome un Screenshot, con el siguiente código:

```
@FXML
private void btnObtenerGraficaClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
{
   capturarImagen();
}

public void capturarImagen() 
{
   try 
   {
      Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
      Robot robot = new Robot();
      Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
      BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
      WritableImage miImagen = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

      // ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("out.jpg"));
      ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("out4.jpg"));
      displayImage.setImage(miImagen);
   } 
   catch (Exception ex) 
   {
      Logger.getLogger(EmiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero antes de ejecutar el método **capturarimagen()** necesito minimizar toda la aplicación, para que me tome la captura de pantalla del escritorio. En este punto es donde surge mi pregunta. Como hacer referencia de mi **primaryStage** desde este escenario poder minimizar la aplicación utilizando:

```
primaryStage.setIconified(true);
```

O en su caso como minimizar toda mi aplicación desde una ventana secundaria.

---

La idea de poner `Thread.sleep(1000 * 5)` era para tener un espacio para poder minimizar la aplicación de manera manual y posteriormente que la aplicación tomara la captura de pantalla, pero al ejecutarlo se me congela la aplicación por los 5 segundos en los que dura el thread.

Comment: Necesitas crear un hilo nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es muy laborioso pero si bastante enredoso. Crea una clase que extienda de `Thread` y dentro de ella pones el código que quieras. Si necesitas ejecutar alguna función solo pasale un `Runnable` como parámetro para que la ejecute. De esa manera no vas a congelar el hilo principal que es `Thread.sleep()` si no que creas otro. Aquí el ejemplo.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

       System.out.println("Estamos en el main.");



      Timer timer;
    timer = new Timer();

      TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        int tic=0;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (tic%2==0)
            System.out.println("TIC");
            else{
                System.out.println("TOC");
            }

            if( tic > 10) {
                System.out.println("Fin del programa");
                cancel();
            }


            tic++;
        }

        // Empezamos dentro de 10ms y luego lanzamos la tarea cada 1000ms

    };
    timer.schedule(task, 10, 1000);

      Hilo hilo = new Hilo();
      hilo.start();

      System.out.println("Termino el main");
    }
}


class Hilo extends Thread {



    @Override
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("Ejecutando hilo");
        System.out.println("Lo detenemos 5 segundos");

        try {
            this.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Se ejecuta la función");
        }catch (Exception ex) 
       {
          System.out.println("Error");
       }


            System.out.println("Fin de la ejecución del hilo.");

    }



}
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó!

Comment: Que bueno!. Puedes hacer una clase que solo le pases un `Runnable` y se acaba el problema de los hilos.

Answer (score 1):

Con la solución propuesta por Ángel, la aplicación no se congela mientras se ejecuta el hilo. comparto código final:

```
introducir el código aquí
 @FXML
    private void btnObtenerGraficaClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Hilo hilo = new Hilo();
        hilo.start();
        System.out.println("[Finalizada]");
    }

    public void capturarImagen() {

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

            WritableImage miImagen = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("o4.jpg"));
            displayImage.setImage(miImagen);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    class Hilo extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                this.sleep(5000);
                capturarImagen();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            System.out.println("Fin de la ejecución del hilo.");

        }
    }
```